# Get an XML from a url using dom

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have store in a String variable(link) the url that I get the xml response, I use a dom to parse the xml data.

In order to be sure that I extract the data correctly I store the xml in the local drive, build my parser and I took the data:

```
document = builder.parse(new File(filepath));
```

So when I try to get it from url I used:

```
document = builder.parse(new URL(link).openStream());
```

And it didn't work. What am I missing?

The data of the xml are stored in a list which then are shown in a jsf datatable.

Comment: "And it didn't work." Any error messages or stack traces, perhaps?

Comment: type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:321)


root cause 

java.lang.NullPointerException

i hope this is helpfull

Comment: i changed the above into the following:
    URL link = new URL("http://.....");
    InputStream in = link.openStream();
    document = builder.parse(in);
and still nothink ...

Answer (score 0):

Well the above works just fine, the problem was the index of elements of the nodelist. For some reason when i was reading from file

`obj.setattribute1(cDetails.item(1).getTextContent());`
`obj.setattribute2(cDetails.item(3).getTextContent());`

see that the item are increased by 2 each time

now that i read a URL the increment is 1 every time

Now i am sure that there is a reason for this which i don't understand probably cause of my limited yet knowledge but the above work and the index of the item increases 1 for the next item in the nodelist.